# Beautiful Soup - issue with brackets in strings?

Tags: beautifulsoup

Beautiful soup seems to have a problem with strings that contain brackets, the following code will fail if `Ethernet LAN (RJ-45`) is entered as a keyword however it will succeed if I enter just `Ethernet LAN`

Does anyone know of a reason why this is, is there anything special I can add to my code to make it work with the brackets as I need a perfect match?

**Code**

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\s*%s\s*' % 'Ethernet LAN (RJ-45) ports quantity')
rj45_ports = soup.find(text=pattern).findNext('div',{'class':'ds_data'}).text
print rj45_ports
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="tableRow">
<div class="ds_label">
<span class=""> Ethernet LAN (RJ-45) ports quantity</span>
<span class="red line">
</div>
<div class="ds_data"> 1 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regex `()`s are special characters. You will need to escape them.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\s*%s\s*' % 'Ethernet LAN \(RJ-45\) ports quantity')
```

It may be worthwhile to write a function that handles sanitizing the strings.

```
def sanitize(s):
    out = s
    # Fill this up with whatever additional meta characters you need to escape
    for meta_char in ['(', ')']:
        out = out.replace(meta_char, '\\'+meta_char)
    return out
```

Comment: That worked extremely well, I have still loads to learn about Python - thanks :)